# How to locate the highest value in a randomly filled two-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, random, variable-assignment, double-pointer

I am making a program that inserts a two-dimensional array with random integers and locates the highest value to display it and its coordinates in the array.

I am using three files:

- utils.h
- utils.cpp
- main.cpp.

```cpp
#include "utils.h"

void fillTable(int table[ROW_COL_SIZE][ROW_COL_SIZE]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < ROW_COL_SIZE; i++) { 
        for(int c = 0; c < ROW_COL_SIZE; c++) { 
            cout << rand() % table[i][c];
        }
    }
} 

void findLargest(int table[ROW_COL_SIZE][ROW_COL_SIZE], int& largestRow, 
                 int& largestCol) {
    largestRow = 0;
    largestCol = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < ROW_COL_SIZE; i++) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < ROW_COL_SIZE; j++) {
            if(table[i][j] > table[largestRow][largestCol]) {
                largestRow = i;
                largestCol = j;
            }
        }
    }
}

void displayTable(int table[ROW_COL_SIZE][ROW_COL_SIZE]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            cout << table[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

My program displays an array, but it is not correct:

```
55302337713078127332504421405961229072248303443307961481223132483391855019110600
92808812679236602328231529150663269913935376911094217591887215022974011255316512
71103276228950168692675422850260269511370054042617128509148242205517590190271332
93168530667935211606208729747118402681321223203422069312038223266476231187148148
05966618422064721159313592422312213211891498452701498229001417726265175102184575
4298481247015001631326472115171254718059341323252489617888241851323216308-858993
460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993
460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993
460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993
460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993
460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993
460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993
460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993
460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993
460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993
460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993
460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993
460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993
460-858993460-858993460-858993460The largest value located at [0] [0] is: -85899
3460
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The only thing I can change is utils.cpp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should `fillTable` fill `table`? Currently it does not - it only prints to `cout`. Therefore, `table` appears to remain uninitialized.

So, in `fillTable`, instead of:

```
cout << rand() % table[i][c];
```

You probably want something like:

```
table[i][c] = rand();
```

Answer (score 0):

In `fillTable` you should use something like:

```
table[i][c] = rand() % MAX_VALUE; // MAX_VALUE is the largest value +1 you want to generate
cout << table[i][c] << " ";
```

(Note the whitespace to separate numbers, you might also want to insert a `cout << endl;` after each row. But I'm not sure if `fillTable` should also print out the values?)

Also the `displayTable` function only prints the first ten lines/columns (but this might be intentional?)

Answer (score 0):

You are just making the random number output and not inserting in it.

Do it this way:

```cpp
table [i][c] = rand () % table [i][c] ;
```

Plus, you are getting a garbage value when you find the largest value because there is no actual value stored in the array.